# List view show user error

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I want to show users list from database in a tab layout in a ListView but getting an error attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String `java.lang.Object.toString()'` on a null object reference. After many searches I did not get success in removing that. Can anyone help me?

Error

> 03-28 23:26:06.652 25767-25767/com.example.avinash.tablayoutcheck
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.avinash.tablayoutcheck, PID: 25767
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                           at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2474)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1301)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1203)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)

UserlistFragment.java

```
  public class UserlistFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "UserList";
ListView usersList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.userlist_fragment,container,false);

    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    usersList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.usersList);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    usersList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDatabaseUser.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           /* list.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));*/

            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }
            list.add(user.username);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

userlist_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/usersList"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK0cP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope I have seen  that answer already but not solved it

Comment: could you post your firebase structure

Comment: just to debug your code, try to remove that Firebase listener and add some dummy data.
and if your listView works as expected, then try to link it with firebase.

Comment: plus move `usersList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.usersList);` to `onCreateView` and replace `getActivity()` with `view`.

Comment: I have added firebase structure

Comment: That's help me by moving to onCreate View